# Where to locate sample Oracle redo log files?

Tags: database, oracle, logging, redo

I'm looking to locate Oracle redo log files, ideally large ones with at least 20MB in size. Any ideas where to look?

Comment: Oracle documentation
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/onlineredo009.htm#ADMIN11328

Comment: Do you mean from your own DB or elsewhere? The 'sample' suggests you're looking for random files from other people's DBs - which are unlikely to be shared (as they'd contain private info), and would be off-topic anyway. I'm almost afraid to ask what you want them for...

Comment: Elsewhere. I need them for ML training.

Comment: Realistically you'll need to generate your own redo in your own DB.

Comment: Right, but I don't have my own DB at the moment. So that's not an option. Appreciate your response.

Comment: @user11147997 did you find any redo log dataset? Actually i am also having the same question, i need one for research purpose.